# How can this Service Method be Unit Tested

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I'm diving into Unit Testing...etc..  I'm stuck trying to test this particular service.  I've seen examples but I can't seem to understand what proper steps are to unit test this simple method:  GetEmployeeProductivity()

```
public class EmployeeService
{
    private IRepository<Employee> _employeeInfoRespository;
    private IEmployeeData_Repository _EmployeeDataRespository;

public Employee GetEmployeeProductivity(Employee employee,String Date1, String Date2)
    {
        Employee newEmp = new Employee();
        newEmp = _EmployeeDataRespository.GetEmployeeDataUsingDates(employee,Date1,Date2);
        return newEmp;
    }

}
```

If it's not testable how can this be rewritten to be testable? Please provide an example.

Comment: What exactly do you want to test in this method or have problem with? The method as shown in the post seem to construct unused object and return value that does not match method name - so it is probably just random partial sample... Otherwise looks properly using mock-able dependency (probably injected via constructor) - so should be trivial to check if mocked `GetEmployeeDataUsingDates` get called with passed in arguments...

Comment: Agreeing with Mr. Levenkov -- your question seems a bit unclear. In general, given a method like that which you want to unit-test -- you would create test cases that call it with known-good argument values, bad argument values (to verify that it throws exceptions or whatever), and ensure you test for edge cases such as nulls, zeros, empty and blank string values, and improperly-formed Date1 and Date2.

Since you are accessing a repository, and this is not an integration-test, you would probably want to use a mock-object in place of that service to test just this function.

Comment: @JamesWHurst Ok.  Can you show an example to test this? So I shouldn't call this a unit test?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the `_EmployeeDataRespository.GetEmployeeDataUsingDates`that goes to the database. You should mock this method.

The method probably need a redesign to. The `= new Employee();` is not needed ad all.

The method is now not much more then a wrapper for an other method. I does not do much on his own.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov To me, it looks like EmployeeData_Repository not an interface so it is harder to mock.

Comment: +1... you are probably right - it would be called `IEmployeeDataRepository` if it is an interface...